# getcwd: cannot access parent directories

Tags: bash, shell, aix

I am facing an error when running pwd command on the AIX console

```
Server_SID:sidadm 8> pwd
`pwd`: The file access permissions do not allow the specified action
```

Also when running a script on the same server I see the following error:

> job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.

Snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
case $choice in

        a)
    echo "current usage of the /audit FS"
        df -P /audit
        space=`df -gt /audit | awk '{print $5}' | grep % | grep -v Use | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -d "%" -f1 -`
        case $space in
            [1-6]*)
                echo "All is quiet.\n"
            ;;
            [7-8]*)
                echo "\nAudit is at $space % full."
            ;;
            9[0-8])
                echo "\nBetter hurry with moving the files...  Audit is at $space % full."
            ;;
            99)
                echo "\nI'm drowning here!  Audit is at $space %!"
            ;;
            *)
                echo " "
            ;;
        esac



echo "**********"
;;

 *)

    echo " have a great day!!"
;;

esac
```

However if I run the same script from a different user then I do not see any issues. Could someone tellme what is the issue here?

OS: AIX 7.1

Comment: Seems like you have permission problems on that user's home directory path. Fix that.

Comment: Guess you tried something you weren't supposed/allowed to -- mind you, permissions and restrictions exist for a reason. Consult a competent sysadmin.